# Is [chestnut] a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've seen the [chestnut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chestnut) tag being added to a lot of puzzles lately, with a vague feeling that there's something "wrong" about it. Today I finally managed to pin down what the problem is: it doesn't really say anything about what *kind* of question is being posed, just that it's - and I quote the tag wiki - a puzzle that "some may have already heard" (which is woolly at best and subjective at worst). It wouldn't work as the *only* tag on a question, which makes it a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). **Does this mean it should be abolished?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a meta tag, mostly because it's opinion-based as to which puzzles the tag should apply to.

I have burned it manually.